# How to get data with JSON format in Clickhouse-driver

Tags: python, clickhouse

I'm trying to get my Clickhouse data in my Django project. I'm using `clickhouse_driver` and :

```
client.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 5 FORMAT JSON')
```

When I execute this command in my Clickhouse server `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 5 FORMAT JSON` it outputs in `JSON` format. But in python, when I try it with clickhouse_driver it outputs only fields like:

`[('2020213','qwerty','asdfg'),('2030103','qweasd','asdxv')]`

But I want key-value json format..like

`{"logdate":"2020213","host":"qwerty","cef":"asdfg"}`

Any suggestions to resolve this problem? Or maybe I have to search for an alternate clickhouse_driver..

Thx.

Comment: Have you tried  Pandas *.to_JSON* and *read_sql*?

Comment: actually its not about types.. its about clickhouse_driver lib. lib does not give keys when we trying to get data, only values.. If i can get keys i will use it :) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not try Vladimir solution but here is the my solution :

**client.execute** commands gives us " **with_column_types=True** " parameters.. it gives us metadata for table. after :

```
result , columns = client.execute('SELECT * FROM myTbl LIMIT 5',with_column_types=True)
df=pandas.DataFrame(result,columns=[tuple[0] for tuple in columns])
dfJson=df.to_json(orient='records')
```

and this gives us our what we want.

Thx for suggestions :)

Answer (score 4):

*clickhouse-driver* ignores FORMAT-clause (see [Selecting data](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=format#selecting-data)).

It can be done either manually by combining column name with related value:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client
from json import dumps

client = Client(host='localhost')

data = client.execute_iter('SELECT * FROM system.functions LIMIT 5', with_column_types=True)
columns = [column[0] for column in next(data)]

for row in data:
    json = dumps(dict(zip(columns, [value for value in row])))
    print(f'''{json}''')

# Result:
# {"name": "fromUnixTimestamp64Nano", "is_aggregate": 0, "case_insensitive": 0, "alias_to": ""}
# {"name": "toUnixTimestamp64Nano", "is_aggregate": 0, "case_insensitive": 0, "alias_to": ""}
# {"name": "toUnixTimestamp64Micro", "is_aggregate": 0, "case_insensitive": 0, "alias_to": ""}
# {"name": "sumburConsistentHash", "is_aggregate": 0, "case_insensitive": 0, "alias_to": ""}
# {"name": "yandexConsistentHash", "is_aggregate": 0, "case_insensitive": 0, "alias_to": ""}
```

or using pandas:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client
import pandas as pd

client = Client(host='localhost')

data = client.execute_iter('SELECT * FROM system.functions LIMIT 5', with_column_types=True)
columns = [column[0] for column in next(data)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
# Result 
# [{"name":"fromUnixTimestamp64Nano","is_aggregate":0,"case_insensitive":0,"alias_to":""},{"name":"toUnixTimestamp64Nano","is_aggregate":0,"case_insensitive":0,"alias_to":""},{"name":"toUnixTimestamp64Micro","is_aggregate":0,"case_insensitive":0,"alias_to":""},{"name":"sumburConsistentHash","is_aggregate":0,"case_insensitive":0,"alias_to":""},{"name":"yandexConsistentHash","is_aggregate":0,"case_insensitive":0,"alias_to":""}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, clickhouse-driver doesn't support FORMAT-clause but if your data stored in JSON type in clickhouse you can get data in key-value  format adding settings={'allow_experimental_object_type': 1} in your command

```
    client.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM test',
        settings={'allow_experimental_object_type': 1}
 )
[({'b': 1}, {'x': 2})]
```

clickhouse-driver: https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#tuple-t1-t2

clickhouse: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/json#displaying-json-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
client.query_dataframe(sql).to_json(orient='records',default_handler=str)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clickhouse driver DBAPI and [DictCursor](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dbapi.html#clickhouse_driver.dbapi.extras.DictCursor). Following is minimum code for illustration.

```py
>>> from clickhouse_driver.dbapi import connect
>>> from clickhouse_driver.dbapi.extras import DictCursor

>>> conn = connect(host='localhost', user='default', password='', database='')
>>> cursor = c.cursor(DictCursor)
>>> cursor.execute('create table test(i Int, s String) engine Memory')
>>> cursor.execute('insert into test values', [(1,'a'),(2,'b')])
>>> cursor.execute('select * from test')
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[{'i': 1, 's': 'a'}, {'i': 2, 's': 'b'}]
```